# Is there a way to set 404 http header in angular 5 when route not matched?

Tags: angular, seo, http-status-code-404

I want to set a header 404 on current page when there is no route matching my array.

Other wise I think it will be a issue in SEO and unknown pages will also be added to search engines.

Comment: What servers your app? IIS?

Comment: no, its apache.

Answer (score -3):

Angular has a route path - `**`, which will be accessed if no route was matched. You can use this path to show `404 error page` component.

```
{ path: '**', component: Error404Component }
```

Comment: This still returns 200 in http header (so it's only a "soft 404")

Comment: This returns 200 because the Error404Component is found. You can't get an error 404 because javascript works for the route, not the server

Comment: It's completely possible to have a 404 page return http 404. It would require information injected to js from your backend.  
Examples: https://blog.thecodecampus.de/angular-universal-handle-404-set-status-codes/, https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/667

Comment: And why you need to do this work ?. Only for getting 404? If you can do something it don't says that you need. It is purpose based. So I don't understand your downvote. You could add your answer below

Comment: -1 because the question asks about **http headers** and is explicitly tagged "http-status-code-404". Your answer does not address this. 

As the asker says, you do need to return 404 for 404 pages otherwise crawlers/scanners are confused by your site.

Comment: The question was another at the first time. The second answer also shows it. Something was edited and the history is not saved. Comparing the answers to the question, they don't match anymore

Answer (score -3):

you can do like this , add below in your rout.ts file and create `notfoundComponent`

```
 {path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent},
 {path: '**', redirectTo: '/404'}

or you can do directly 

 {path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent}
```